# How i can remove span in the CF7 without touching error span?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', function($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('/<(span).*?class="\s*(?:.*\s)?wpcf7-form-control-wrap(?:\s[^"]+)?\s*"[^\>]*>(.*)<\/\1>/i', '\2', $content);

    return $content;
});
```

i using this code, but this code delete all span ,error too , but i want to display error message

Comment: why do you want to remove the span elements?

Comment: @Aurovrata - because it breaks layout. eg. in Bootstrap 4 forms with `prepend` elements

Comment: understood, will post an answer below

Answer (score 1):

The CF7 form uses a `<div class="wpcf7-response-output"></div>` to display error messages, so I am not sure what you mean by the span error.

The CF7 plugin uses a span element for its validation tip messages which are displayed for invalid fields post submission.  These can filtered using the `wpcf7_validation_error` [hook](http://hookr.io/filters/wpcf7_validation_error/).

However, I would not recommend deleting the field wrap as this is used by many plugins including cf7 to target/style cf7 form elements.  I would instead suggest you replace them with a `<div>` element for example, and simply add a css style rule to your form pages to display `div.wpcf7-form-control-wrap` inline.

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', function($content) {
  $content = str_replace('<span', '<div', $content);
  $content = str_replace('</span', '</div', $content);
  return $content;
});
```

so in addition I would add the following css style rules to the form pages,

```
div.wpcf7-form-control-wrap{display:inline}
div.wpcf7-list-item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}
div.wpcf7-list-item-label::before,
div.wpcf7-list-item-label::after {
    content: " ";
}
```

Keep in mind that the cf7 plugin targets quiz label span specifically in the js script file loaded by the plugin, hence if you need to use quiz fields then you will need to find an alternative approach to your problem.